# Contradicting Results of Complex Number Product

Tags: complex-numbers

It is required to find the smallest value of $p \in Q^{+}$ such that $(z_1z_2)^{p}$ is a positive real number where $z_1z_2=cos(\frac{11\pi}{12})+isin(-\frac{11\pi}{12})$ where $Arg(z)=\frac{-11\pi}{12}$. So using De Moivres theorem we get  $$(z_1z_2)^p=cos(\frac{11\pi p}{12})-isin(\frac{11\pi p}{12})$$ In order to have purely real we must have $$ -sin(\frac{11\pi p}{12})=0$$ $$p=\frac{24}{11}$$ Is the smallest $p$ which gives positive real component. This all seemed fine to me until I used $Arg(z)=\frac{13\pi}{12}$ instead of $Arg(z)=-\frac{11\pi}{12}$. This gives $$sin(\frac{13\pi}{12})=0$$ $$p=\frac{24}{13}$$

So there must be a flaw somewhere here since we can't have two different values of $p$ for two identical scenarios. So where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $(e^{i\theta})^{p}=e^{ip\theta}$ is not valid unless $p$ is an integer.

Comment: ah yes. I completely forgot about that condition thank you. So, how could this be solved?

Comment: What is $z$? And what is the purpose of $z_1, z_2$? They do not occur individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raising a complex number to a fractional power is a multivalued operation. For example $(e^{i \pi})^{\frac12}=\pm i$. Or  $(e^{i \frac{\pi}3})^{\frac19}$ has nine different values, some but not all of which are real.
In your case, you should say
$$z_1z_2=\cos \frac{(11\pi+24 \pi n) }{12}-i \sin \frac{(11\pi+24 \pi n) }{12}$$
$$(z_1z_2)^p=\cos \frac{(11\pi+24 \pi n) p}{12}-i \sin \frac{(11\pi+24 \pi n) p}{12}$$
for some integer $n$. For this to be real,
$$\frac{(11\pi+24\pi  n) p}{12} = m \pi $$
for some integer $m$. So,
$$p=\frac{12 m } {11+24n } $$
This gives many values of $p$ where one of the possible values of $(z_1z_2)^p$ is real. There is no smallest positive such value of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the *interpretation* of an expression $z^x$ with $z \in \mathbb C$ and $x \in \mathbb R$. For a *real* $z$ the standard definiton is $z^x = e^{x\ln z}$ with the real logarithm $\ln z$. But if $z$ is non-real, then the expression $\ln z$ is no longer unique. In fact, $\ln z$ is a complex number such that $e^{\ln z } = z$. There are infinitely many such numbers, any two differing by an integral multiple of $2\pi i$ (*branches of the complex logarithm*). Often one takes the principal value of $\ln z$ which is unique solution of $e^{\ln z} = z$ with imaginary part in $[0,2\pi)$.

For your $z = z_1z_2$ you get $\ln z = -\frac{11\pi i}{12} + 2k \pi i $ with $k \in \mathbb Z$. For $k = 0$ you get the value $-\frac{11\pi i}{12}$, for $k = 1$ the value $\frac{13\pi i}{12}$. Anyway
$$z^p = e^{p(-\frac{11\pi i}{12} + 2k \pi i)} = e^{p(-\frac{11 }{12} + 2k )\pi i}.$$

Thus $z^p$ is real if any only if $p(-\frac{11}{12} + 2k)$ is an even integer, i.e.
$$p(-\frac{11}{12} + 2k) = 2 m$$
with some $m \in \mathbb Z$. This gives
$$p = \frac{24m}{24k-11} .$$

For $k = 0$ and $m = -1$ we get $p = \frac{24}{11}$, for $k = 1$ and $m = 1$ we get $p = \frac{24}{13}$.

For a fixed $k$ we get infintely many $p$, but there is a smallest positive solution (obtained for $m =1$ if $k > 0$ and for $m =-1$ if $k\le 0$).

If arbitary $k$ are allowed, then there does not exist a smallest positive solution $p$.

Perhaps the "correct understanding" of your question is to work with $\ln z = \frac{-11 \pi i}{12}$, i.e. with $k = 0$.